# Paypal Ipn Canceled Reversal

Tags: php, paypal-ipn, payment-processing

I have try to search for my problem here and on x.com but can't find anything, Then i like to ask.

The problem is the Canceled_Reversal status.

1. When i got this status how can i check if we won the case or we lost?
   Because what i found out was this means both Win/Lost
2. When i got this status will there come a complete status after ?

**What i think i should work**

What i need it for is because i need to find out if the member have lost the dispute or we won it. Because then the user not should have access to content i the user won but if we won he still have access

**How i use it right now **
if(Compelete) as paid
if(Pending) as waiting
if($payment_status == "Voided" || $payment_status == "Expired") as Rejected
if($payment_status == "Reversed" || $payment_status == "Refunded" || $payment_status == "Canceled_Reversal") as Refunded

1. But when i got a pending then will paypal a complete after right ?

**If you have any recommendations i like to hear it**

**Hope someone can help me out here :)**

Comment: I don't know why anybody thinks this is not a real question. It is.

Answer (score 2):

I might be able to explain the findings in the original question as well as the experiment run by user4416494.

The key is to understand that the PayPal fee is a constant amount plus a percentage of the purchase price.  When a refund is made, the customer gets their *full* amount returned.  But PayPal always keeps the fee.  That means the merchant actually loses money.  They lose the full, original purchase price (since that went back to the customer) AND they must provide the fee that PayPal keeps.

So, for example, if I make a donation of $5.00 to an organization, and then the organization refunds the $5.00, I get the full $5.00 back.  But the organization does NOT come out even.  They actually lose the fee that PayPal keeps for the transaction.  (I haven't found this detail in the PayPal documentation, but I've verified it from my own IPNs.)

The seemingly awkward use of Canceled-Reversal--even for a dispute the merchant lost--is how PayPal "simplfies" this handling of the fee.

Consider a $5.00 purchase.  If PayPal charges 2.2% + 30 cents, then the merchant gets paid $4.59 and PayPal keeps 41 cents.

(See the following stack overflow question with example messages provided by PayPal:  [PayPal IPN Example: Completed, Reversed, Canceled_Reversed and Refunded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451449/paypal-ipn-example-completed-reversed-canceled-reversed-and-refunded))

The sequence for a dispute that the merchant WON is this (Original purchase: $5.00):

- Completed: $4.59
- Reversed: $-4.59
- Canceled-Reversal: 4.59
- **SUM: $4.59**

So when all is said and done, the merchant account ends up with the amount they would have received if a dispute was never filed: $4.59.

Here is the sequence for a $5.00 purchase for a dispute the merchant lost:

- Completed: $4.59
- Reversal: $-4.59
- Canceled_Reversal: $4.59
- Refunded: $-5.00
- **SUM: -0.41**

So you can see the customer gets all their money back, and the merchant loses money so to pay for the fee that PayPal keeps.

- If the customer wins the dispute, they get a full Refund.
- The merchant foots the bill for the full refund, including the fee that that PayPal keeps.
- PayPal does not issue BOTH a Reversal and a Refund to the customer.  That means the merchant would be charged twice and the customer would get twice the original purchase price back.
- So the "Reversal" can be seen as temporary.  *It will be canceled one way or the other*.
- If the merchant wins, the Reversal is canceled and that's the end of it.
- But in the case of a dispute the customer won, the Reversal is reversed, **and replaced by** a full Refund.
- This is how PayPal actually makes sure the books balance (see the EJP comment near the end of the EJP answer).

EDIT
Here is a more detailed reply that includes fee.  (These numbers come from the IPNs reported at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451449/paypal-ipn-example-completed-reversed-canceled-reversed-and-refunded) Stack Overflow page.)

Dispute won by merchant:

```
Status            mc_gross  mc_fee 
==================================      
Completed             5.00    0.45 
Reversed             -4.55   -0.45 
Canceled_Reversal     4.55    0.45
===================================
SUM                   5.00    0.45
```

Dispute won by customer:

```
Status            mc_gross  mc_fee 
==================================      
Completed             5.00    0.45 
Reversed             -4.55   -0.45 
Canceled_Reversal     4.55    0.45
Refunded             -5.00   -0.15 
===================================
SUM                      0    0.30
```

Interestingly, this shows that PayPal only keeps the constant part of the fee for a refund, and not the part of the fee based on a percentage of the purchase price.

Answer (score 1):

Reversal means that Paypal reversed the transaction. They have the money. Canceled_reversal means that they cancelled the reversal. You have the money. You won the case.

> Because what i found out was this means both Win/Lost

I don't know where you got that idea. From the IPN Guide:

> Canceled_Reversal: A reversal has been canceled. For example, you won
>   a dispute with the customer, and the funds for the transaction that
>   was reversed have been returned to you.

Comment: I think there is more to it. I have a 
Canceled_Reversal  (funds returned,   mc_gross = 10)
and in the next 5 seconds i have another call , txn_type = "adjustment" with reason_code=chargeback_settlement where the funds are taken again, mc_gross = -10  So, .. did i won the dispute ? :)

Comment: I also have this issue, Canceled_Reversal happens in both cases of the charge being won by seller or buyer

Comment: @aconrad Canceled_reversal means what they said above, and the following adjustment appears to mean that they changed their mind.

Comment: @MatthewJames You seem to be confusing the original Reversal with Canceled_reversal.

Comment: @EJP ok. to be clear what I mean is I get a Canceled_Reversal in both cases: buyer won and seller won. The only difference is the mc_gross amounts are +ve and -ve respectively.

Ihe paypal documentation doesn't indicate this, it only indicates Canceled_Reversal in favour of the seller... as far as I can see

Comment: Weird. Your books wouldn't balance if it did that. They have sent you two debuts for the same amount: one in the reversal and one in the cancel.

Comment: @EJP: You can see my more detailed reply below.  The Canceled_Reversal happens in both cases exactly so the books do balance.  In the case of a dispute that the customer won, the Reversal is canceled, then REPLACED BY a full refund.  You're absolutely right about the PalPal documentation failing to include this essential information.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this today. The IPN payment_status's I receive for the Fraud Reversal case are as follows:

Completed (on purchase)
Reversed (on "Fraud" dispute)

Seller Won:
Canceled_Reversal

Buyer Won:
Canceled_Reversal
Reversed